# How to ensure only physical Smart Meters can update blockchain data?

Tags: ethereumjs

Hey fellow blockchain enthusiasts!

I'm working on a project where I need to ensure that only physical smart meters can update the data on a blockchain-based Smart Contract. It's crucial to prevent malicious users from tampering with the system.

Imagine a scenario where anyone can deploy their own Smart Contract instance. How can I make sure that data changes are only permitted by the genuine physical smart meters and not by someone attempting to forge data from their PC?

I'm interested in any insights or strategies you might have to bolster the security of this setup.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called [trusted computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Computing).

- Each smart meter must be physically protected against tampering
- Each smart meter is provisioned with a private key at the factory - a key that cannot be extracted or changed afterwards
- The matching public key is recorded on an audit log, which itself can live on a blockchain
- Smart meter signs their transactions with its private key and this way you can be sure that data coming from smart meters is always genuine

However, this does not prevent messing with analog inputs (disconnecting the meter) to fool it.